# What is the Rank of Matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Let $x$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be non-zero column vectors, from the matrix $A=xy^{T}$, where $y^{T}$ is the transpose of $y$. Then the rank of $A$ is ?

---

I am getting $1$, but need confirmation .

Answer (score 2):

For every vector $v$, we have $Av = x y^Tv= x (y^Tv)$. $(y^Tv)$ is a scalar, so $Av$ is contained in the span of the one dimensional space generated by $x$.

Comment: Alternatively: we have the rank inequality $rank(xy^T) \leq \min\{rank(x),rank(y^T)\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Each row of $A$ is a multiple of $x$, so each pairs of rows in $A$ is linearly dependent. Hence, the rank of $A$ is at most 1. If $x=\mathbf{0}$ or $y=\mathbf{0}$, of course, the rank is $0$.